# ng-click not working in font-awesome icon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, font-awesome

I have added my demo to: [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/edoist/wewekvkw/14/) When I click on thumbs up (comes from fontawesome) ng-click does not trigger and like count does not change. When I click to xyz, like count increases.

This is not working:

```
<i ng-click="LikeComment(comment)" class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i> {{comment.like}}
```

But this is working:

```
<i ng-click="LikeComment(comment)">xyz</i> {{comment.like}}
```

Comment: You should wrap icons with actions in a button: `<button ng-click="LikeComment(comment)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button`

Comment: ```<div ng-click="LikeComment(comment)"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i> {{comment.like}}</div>``` div will make it as well ;p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<span ng-click="LikeComment(comment)"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></span>{{comment.like}}
```

**OR**, in case you are ok with a button

```
<button ng-click="LikeComment(comment)"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>{{comment.like}}
```

Comment: This solution is working fine, but may I know why this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Font awesome turns it into a `<svg>` tag which doesn't seem to collaborate too well with the click handler. Try wrapping the `<i>` in a `<div>` like this

https://jsfiddle.net/wewekvkw/26/